# What is standard Kryptonian food?

Tags: dc, superman, krypton

What did the kryptonians actually eat while they were living on krypton? I guess, they didn't eat the same things that humans eat.

Comment: They eat [Kryptonian food](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9ODNoOL20c). Except that they just call it 'food'

Comment: Lol! I actually meant what WE would call it besides “food” @Valorum

Comment: Presumably, Kryptonian "food" is simply edible plants and animals. There have been a few mentioned species of Kryptonian animals. For example, Superman keeps a Thought-Beast, native to Krypton, in the Fortress of Solitude. The Oregus Plant's juice has been mentioned to be used in cooking before, a plant native to Krypton. Not sure of any others.

Comment: H'Raka meat is apparently tasty..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest taking a wander thru "A Kryptonian Bestiary" (http://mindmistress.tumblr.com/page/7 )  A delightful collection of the biosphere of comic book Krypton.

Page 7 shows that Krypton enjoyed the "feast tree" that produced multiple fruits as well as digging into "roast babootch".

Comment: I notice that the link now leads to nothing.  How sad such a great resource has fallen off the web.